# What form-factors do PSUs use nowadays?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer, atx, desktop-customization

I'm building a desktop and I'm going to get the SilverStone SST-ST50F 500W as my PSU. What form-factor is it?

Is it ATX, following the motherboard form-factor or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ATX" when used with a PSU refers to the power and signaling specifications.

Standard PSUs have had the same form factor for a very long time, all the way back to the AT PSU days. The only difference is the number and arrangement of power pins, and the use of a physical switch versus soft-signaling.

And yes, the PSU you name should work with a ATX motherboard.